# Magento - Unable to Refresh Product Stock Status on the Product Page

Tags: magento, product, stock

One of our Vendors has a real time inventory system and we would like to implement it into our site. When a person clicks on the product, it should check the inventory and update as necessary. This works ok at best. The problem is when the product switches to in/out of stock. It updates properly in the backend, but I am unable to get the addtocart button to be added/removed. This is my code for updating the stock:

```
//$_stockQTY is the realtime inventory result

$stockData = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
$stockData->loadByProduct($_product->getId());
$stockData->setData('qty', $_stockQTY);                    
$stockData->setData('is_in_stock',($_stockQTY > 0) ? 1 : 0); 
 if ($stockData->dataHasChangedFor('qty')) {
    $stockData->save();
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
}
```

As you can see, I am force reloading the product when qty is changed. This seems to work for everything but the addtocart button. It shows the previous result (In stock or out of stock before the reload.)

I have 2 questions:

Is there a better way to reload a product other than reassigning it as I am doing above:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
```

And why is it that everything is updating properly, but the addtocart which uses the same

`$_product->isSaleable()`

call that our availability, etc uses.

Compare:

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <p class="availability in-stock"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/stock.png') ?>"> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span>
...
?>
```

To

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?> //Only Shows up if addtocart does not.
```

Refreshing the page will update the product properly, but doing a meta refresh or anything of the sorts is out of the question.  I appreciate any advice that could be given as I would like to get this resolved and on to the next task.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, it appears the thorn in your side is the stock status index.

Try this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock_status')->updateStatus($_product->getId());
```

(I haven't tested this, but it looks like it ought to work)